# How to add resources file to my phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I'am using [Cordova LocalNotification-Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) to show some notification to user . Now what I want to do is to have a specific sound on notification . They said to add this

`window.plugin.notification.local.add({ sound: 'android.resource://' + package_name +/raw/beep});`

Note: Local sound files must be placed into the res-folder and not into the assets-folder.

I don't know in which res folder should I put my mp3. And if I try to put it into main res folder where I have : drawable; drawable-hdpi; drawable-ldpi;drawable-mdpi;drawable-xhdpi;values;xml folders when I build the project I get this error:

> invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\etc\etc\myprojectname\platforms\android\res/sounds

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you should put your sound file in the res/raw folder instead of res/sounds (as you see in the plugin call : +/**raw**/beep).

There is no /res/sounds folder in android, datas that do not fit in other categories should be put in /res/raw.
You can have a look at the [sdk doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: Yes. You're right . The folder needs to be called raw but I still can't get the song played. 'android.resource://' + package_name +/raw/beep -> what about the package_name with what I should replace it ?

Comment: I figured it out . The package_name was the name of my application package. Thanks QuickFix for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right you should just create the missing var and assign your package name (the one you use when created the phonegap/cordova project with the command line something like this for example:

```
cordova create LocalNotification com.example.localnotification LocalNotification
```

Should be used in the plugin with these values:

```
var package_name = "com.example.localnotification";
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
        date        : Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000 + 5),
        title       : "Android App Tes Local Notification", 
        message       : "This is a new local notification.",
        repeat        : "daily",
        sound       : 'android.resource://' + package_name + '/raw/beep',
        badge           : 0,
        id             : 666,
        foreground      : function(notificationId){
        console.log("Hello World! This alert was triggered by notification " + notificationId);
    },
    background  : function(notificationId){
        console.log("Hello World! This alert was triggered by notification " + notificationId);
    }           
});
```

And just in case someone is interested on creating local notifications for android this is absolutely beautiful and working just fine!

[Download local notification plugin (working on Android ONLY)](https://github.com/jonbarlo/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#examples)

[Download beep.mp3](http://soundjax.com/reddo/54324%5EBEEP2.mp3)