# Which local notification plugin should I be using with phonegap build?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, localnotification

It appears that there are four different 3rd party plugins to accomplish local notifications listed within phonegap build:

https://github.com/GotCakes/Phonegap-LocalNotification/

https://github.com/javamrright/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

https://github.com/simplec-dev/LocalNotification/

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

(from https://build.phonegap.com/plugins)

I've been using the last of the four (de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification) but I'm curious to know (1) whether one of the other packages is the preferred solution and (2) why are there four independent projects within phonegap/cordova to accomplish the same task...?

Comment: Who cares Stackoverflow is a central point for technical questions.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be one of the most active (check contributors/forks etc...):
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Just tested it myself (Android for now) and it works good.

There are different versions/packages of this extension because for the most part, development of Cordova plugins are an open-source affair. Developers far and wide each have their own ideas and best-practice-know-hows on how plugins should work.

Comment: For anyone searching for this more recently - I'm using this plugin and it works well, but development seems to have stalled. 30+ pull requests and the original author is looking for a new maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

Hi guys in this previous question [Local notification in phonegap 3.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979132/local-notification-in-phonegap-3-3-0) you will find documentation and sample code in one of my comments, i'm also providing a beep.mp3 file that you can download and use immediately (which is not provided in the original repo https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

Hope it helps!